# Private channels data does not get received by clients

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pusher

I am not able to get private channels to work using Pusher and Laravel broadcasting. In the `routes/channels.php` file it seems that none of the function gets fired:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});


Broadcast::channel('testevent.{id}', function ($user, $id)
{
    //This never fires
    dd("ENTERED HERE");
    return TRUE;
});
```

In the `BroadcastServiceProvider.php` I have:

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:api']);

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

The `Javascript file` handling data on the client side (using Echo):

```
Echo.private('testevent.1').listen('TestEvent', function(e)
{
    console.log(e);
});
```

Using public channels works perfect. But as soon as I try to create private channels the data is not sent to the client listening for the data. What could the problem be?

Thanks for any help and guidance!

EDIT:

In the Pusher web console it does not appear that the client has subscribed for the "testevent.1" channel. If I change this to a public channel the subscription gets registered.

Answer (score -1):

At the "[Defining authorization callbacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#defining-authorization-callbacks)" paragraph of the Laravel Broadcast documentation, you can see that privates channels need to authenticate users before that they be able to listen to them.

So in in your `routes/channels.php`, you need there to write authentication logic, for exemple :

```
Broadcast::channel('testevent.{id}', function ($user, $id)
{
    return $user->id === $user::findOrFail($id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I do in the first code snippet in the question. I return true for all users just for testing it. But that does not work. It does not even seem to fire the Broadcast::channel code snippet. I have tried to put "dd" in order to see if it enters. But no luck.

Comment: Can you also post your related event class so ?